# Google Chrome really slow loading pages (single-threaded blocking process)

Tags: google-chrome, performance, fedora, speed, chromium

### Version

Performance degradation using Chrome version 84.0.4147.125 and Chromium version 84.0.4147.89 on Fedora 32 (Kernel 5.7.15-200.fc32.x86_64)

### Problem

Realy slow render speed when opening a new tab in both Google Chrome and Chromium on my Fedora 32 workstation using KDE Plasma 5. Firefox is quick but sadly I prefer using Google Chrome which is faster than Firefox (see edit below) in normal conditions. Maybe the problem is related to something else on my system which I can't figure out what it is.

## TL;DR

**I have some single-threaded blocking process that makes my browsing experience super slow when using Chrome/Chromium on Fedora32 that may take up to 45 seconds to load one specific page.**

In Chrome Out of the 6 pages that open automatically, one takes up to 45 seconds to load. If I open the same link in Firefox its to fast to even try to measure the speed.

It takes 19s to load the page when adding this link as the only tab in chromium and opening the app.

If I open a new tab and put that specific link it also takes forever...
When I go in dev-tools/network click Disable Cache in a new tab takes **10.36s / 12.32s** but if I refresh the page it takes only **646ms / 1.77s** (DOMContent Load/load) with cache disabled.

[image: Processes usage displayed during the initial load]

### My system

I have a 10c/20t **5.1 GHz** i9 processor (OC i9-10900x) **32GB** ram and TitanXp Nvidia GPU I can't determine what is blocking the app because it's happening on chrome/chromium main process but only one processor of the multicore CPU is used as you can see from the image above.

### What I have tried

I have browsed the internet for a solution, therefore, I already have tried to:

- Remove all tabs that open automatically,
- Disable all extensions,
- Remove hardware acceleration,
- Clear cache and cookies
- Reboot the computer
- Restart chrome...

---

## Edit

Chrome **beta** 85.0.4183.69 (Build officiel)

**First load (caching disabled)**

- **Finish: 19.27 s** / DOMContentLoaded: 14.91 s / Load: 17.76 s
- 43.0 MB / 48.1 MB transferred (376 requests)

**New Tab (caching disabled)**

- **Finish: 13.80 s** / DOMContentLoaded: 10.41 s / Load: 12.81 s
- 43.0 MB / 48.1 MB transferred (376 requests)

**Reload (caching disabled)**

- **Finish: 2.78 s** / DOMContentLoaded: 589 ms / Load: 1.94 s
- 43.0 MB / 48.1 MB transferred (376 requests)

  **(vs. FireFox 79.0 64 bits):**

  - **Finish: 5.19 s** / DOMContentLoaded: 153 ms / load: 4.09 s
  - 20.58 Mo / 22.95 Mo transferred (186 requests)

**From Link (cache enabled)**

- **Finish: 2.15 s** / DOMContentLoaded: 372 ms / Load: 983 ms
- 56.8 kB / 24.0 MB transferred (188 requests)

  **(vs. FireFox 79.0 64 bits):**

  - **Finish: 3.41 s** / DOMContentLoaded: 142 ms / load: 392 ms
  - 67.58 Ko / 22.62 Mo transferred (137 requests)

Chrome **beta** 85.0.4183.69 DevTools:
[image: REndering time first load]

> Loading this page:
>
> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Luxcium.pop-n-lock-theme-vscode

Comment: try new version of chrome. i.e. version 84.0.4147.135

Comment: FWIW this website is very slow on my computer as well...

Comment: @hedgie It is a slow web site but it should not be taking 20 secondes to first load the page in a new tab after loading Chrome when it takes only milliseconds to reload and less than 3 sec to reload the page with caching disabled.

Comment: @C.F.G Tanks for the idea, I do not have access to the 84.[...].135  version so I installed both DEV and BETA and the times are similar.